# Rails Nested Resources Wrong Number of Arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to figure out a Ruby on Rails routing issue.  Here's the relevant portion of the routes.rb file:

```
resources :clients do
  resources :campaigns do
    resources :targets do
      member do
        post 'send'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`rake routes` includes this:

```
send_client_campaign_target POST   /clients/:client_id/campaigns/:campaign_id/targets/:id/send(.:format) targets#send
```

However, a POST to `/clients/1/campaigns/1/targets/30/send` returns the following error:

```
ArgumentError in TargetsController#send

wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
```

The error page shows the parameters as:

```
{"client_id"=>"1",
 "campaign_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"30"}
```

Any idea what's wrong?  Am I right that this is a routing issue?  The send method exists in the targets controller, but it's an empty stub method and is still generating this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object#send` is defined in Ruby and is called frequently in Rails framework. It's a bad idea to override this method. You need to choose another name.

Comment: This was exactly what was happening.  I didn't realize that I was overriding a method instead of just defining an action.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Accept params, it just an argument error. You are not taking any argument in #send action.